# Phoenix Live View - 'mount' gets called multiple time when subscribed to a publisher

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, publish-subscribe, phoenix-live-view

I encountered a problem inside my demo phoenix application.
The application consists of an api which listens for message jsons and creates an appropriate entry into the ecto data base.

```erlang
defmodule ServerLive.Messages.Message do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "messages" do
    field :content, :string
    field :sender_id, :integer
    field :timestamp, :utc_datetime

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

There is also a live view which displays the entries inside the message table. My goal is to implement an update on the live view and prepend the created message inside the socket whenever a message is being successfully created. For that I have tried to use the `PubSub` module and introduced a subscription to the topic `"messaging"` when the live view is being mounted.

```erlang
defmodule ServerLiveWeb.Demo do
  use ServerLiveWeb, :live_view

  alias ServerLive.Messages

  @topic "messaging"

  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    # mount all messages in reverse order
    socket = assign(socket, :messages, Enum.reverse(Messages.list_messages()))
    # subscribe to messaging
    ServerLiveWeb.Endpoint.subscribe(@topic)
    {:ok, socket}
  end

  ...

  def handle_event("insert", message, socket) do
    socket = update(socket, :messages, fn m -> message <> m end)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

The broadcast is being exectued from the message api controller

```erlang
defmodule ServerLiveWeb.MessageController do
  use ServerLiveWeb, :controller

  alias ServerLive.Messages

  @topic "messaging"

  def create(conn, %{"message" => message_params}) do
    with {:ok, %Message{} = message} <- Messages.create_message(message_params) do
      # broadcast message
      ServerLiveWeb.Endpoint.broadcast(@topic, "insert", message)
      |> put_status(:created)
      |> put_resp_header("location", Routes.message_path(conn, :show, message))
    end
  end

  ...
```

Now the issue is that every time a an api request creates a message and a broadcast is performed, the `mount` function gets called instead of the event handle for an insert. What could be the problem?

I have already investigated with the debugger and the call stack of a second mount call is:

- ServerLiveWeb.Demo.mount/3
- Phoenix.LiveView.Utils.maybe_call_mount!/3
- Phoenix.LiveView.Channel.verified_mount/5
- Phoenix.LiveView.Channel.handle_info/2

Comment: It looks like you're redirecting the user after the create was performed, is that correct? If so, that's equivalent to a page refresh and therefore the mount will be called again.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to your issue, but [`mount` actually gets called twice](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#c:mount/3), so you might want to use [`connected?/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#connected?/1) to only subscribe once the websocket is open. More explanations [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveView.html#module-life-cycle).

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be the double called of mount. One for static and second for when the socket is connected

```
def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
  ServerLiveWeb.Endpoint.subscribe(@topic)
  {:ok, socket}
end
```

If you put the subcribe witin an IF as follows:

```
if connected?(socket), do: ServerLiveWeb.Endpoint.subscribe(@topic)
```

It should work as [@sabiwara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13979518/sabiwara) said.